# R boxplot showing flat lines instead of the box plot

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplotly

I am trying to a multiple plots under two dataset groupings under x-axis against a y-axis.

This is the plot i get:
[image: Problem]

This is the plot i am hoping to achieve:
[image: Expected results]

Below are my codes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)
library(ggExtra)

# Create a box plot with colored boxes and labels
ggplot(testbp, aes(x = Dataset, y = Values, fill = Model)) +
geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE, alpha = 0.4)
```

Comment: Depending on the data, the output could be completely correct. If the spread of the values for one group is small compared to the differences between groups, the result are these horizontal lines.

Comment: Or it happens if all groups only contain a single value: `boxplot(1:3 ~ c("a","b","c"))`.